# Google Earth Engine: Extract rule based values from List and Array

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, list, array

I'm wondering how to extract values from a ee.List and ee.Array that meet a certain criteria in the Google Earth engine environment.

```
var array1 = ee.Array([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4])
var list1 = ee.List([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4])
```

I was thinking in the lines of filtering but I don't know the property to filter on, should I .set() that beforehand somehow?

```
var output = list1.filter(ee.Filter.gt('Item',2))
```

I assume I should use .slice for the array, but can't find an example that uses slice on a filtered array or conditional statement.

Wondering if somebody can guide me in the correct direction!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask() an array using a conditional:

```
var array1 = ee.Array([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4])
var masked = array1.mask(array1.eq(2))
```

You can't however mask a list.  But you can filter it the way you've already mentioned (filter using 'item').